# Export Excel 97-2003 (xls) with template (VBA macros and format, style) without COM

Tags: c#, excel, xls, vba

I have an Excel template 97-2003 (xls) which contains some VBA macros, format/formula and style and I put it on my web application (ASP.Net MVC, c#) and I'm stuck in writing function 'export data filled in this Excel template without using COM, result format must be *.xls'. And I need to update the VBA macros programmatically tool. I've tried Excellibrary https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/ but it only save as the cells content. And EPPlus library don't work for xls.

Comment: What's wrong with using COM (Office Interop)? This is what it's _for_.

Comment: Because of my poor hosting and reducing cost from cloud service.
Performance of COM is bad for large volume users too

Comment: Hi, I need export to xls not xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Going with COM interface for MS Excel is the easiest option to write XLS (but please notice that Microsoft [is not recommending](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757) to use Office components in server-side apps due to some technical and licensing considerations.)

There are couple of 3rd party commercial .NET (with .NET interface) components which are capable of reading and writing XLS:

- [Gembox.Spreadsheet](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/)
- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/.net/excel-component.aspx)
- [Infragistics Excel](http://www.infragistics.com/products/windows-forms/frameworks/infragistics-excel-framework)
- [Spreadsheet Gear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/products/spreadsheetgear.net.aspx)
- [ByteScout Spreadsheet SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/bytescoutspreadsheetsdk.html)

Disclosure: I am affiliated with ByteScout